# Long.valueOf no muestra cero a la izquierda

Tags: java, android

Tengo un problema al momento de hacer un append a un `StringBuilder` desde un `linkedList` y mostrarlo en forma de long, el código es el siguiente:

```
   for (int i=0; i < new_list.size(); i++)
    {
        stb.append(new_list.get(i));
        Log.d("numbers stored", String.valueOf(new_list.get(i)));
    }

    Log.d("each value from", String.valueOf(new_list.toString()));
    Long requestLong = Long.parseInt(stb.toString());
    Log.d("each value from", String.valueOf(requestLong));
    return Long.valueOf(requestLong);
```

el valor del `LinkedList` resulta esto:

```
[0, 8, 4, 6, 8, 9, 7, 0]
```

el cual es el deseado pero al momento de hacer el append y utlizar el metodo de `Long.valueOf` el resultado es el siguiente: `8468970`

¿Cómo puedo hacer para mostrar exactamente el valor que está almacenado en el `LinkedList`?, por su atención, gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En el momento en que pasas el `String` a `Long` pasas de tener un texto a un número, y un núumero nunca tendrá un 0 a la izquierda. Al igual que te pasaria con `Integers`, `Floats` o en tu caso `Longs`.

Para conservar ese 0 a la izquierda debes conservarlo en un `String` para que se mantenga como texto y no te elimine ese 0 que necesitas.

Comment: tienes razón, el 0 a la izquierda, java lo toma como un número octal y por tanto tendría que hacer algunos ajustes para poder obtener el valor deseado. Muchas gracias por tu respuesta.

Comment: De nada! Me alegro de haberte ayudado! Un saludo!

Comment: Tengo el mismo problema, necesito un long que acepte ceros a la izquierda

Comment: Eso no es posible, un long nunca tendrá ceros. Deberás buscar otra forma de hacerlo